# Read/Write to serail port RS232

Tags: java, serial-port

I am using A software called ASTM protocol Demo to send ASTM messages and another software Virtual Serial Port to use a Port RS232

My question is: I want to create a java project that can access this port and read/write messages from/to this port.

[image]

Comment: [Java Serial Communication on Windows](//stackoverflow.com/q/264277)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RX/TX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). 
There is a lot of info on the web about how to use it.
for [example](http://www.kuligowski.pl/java/rs232-in-java-for-windows,1).